# How to play multiple video on top of each other with ffmpeg c programming

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, sdl

I'm trying to develop a code which can plays multiple videos simultaneously with ffmpeg.
I need to play a video on a 2x2 matrix background and another video in the top left corner of it.
Problem : The top left corner video is flicking and not stable enough.
[top-left video is flicking while playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poGO0.png)
code :

```
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 24, 0);
void video_display(VideoState *is) {
  SDL_Rect rect;
  VideoPicture *vp;
  int w, h, x, y;
  h = screen->h;
  w = ((int)rint(h * aspect_ratio)) ;
  if(w > screen->w) {
    w = screen->w;
    h = ((int)rint(w / aspect_ratio)) ;
  }

  rect.x = (screen->w - w) / 2;
  rect.y = (screen->h - h) / 2;

  if(  is->video_id == 0 ){
     rect.w = w;
     rect.h = h;
     SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(vp->bmp, &rect); // i think the problem is over here
  }
  else if( is->video_id == 1 ){
     rect.w = w/2;
     rect.h = h/2;
     SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(vp->bmp, &rect);
  }
```

When i choose 0/1, i move between audio only.
My question is : What should i code in order to make the top-left video stable to view?

Comment: Can you use a double buffered screen, and ensure that the top-left video frame is always the last one displayed before flipping the buffers (even if you're just reshowing the same frame)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: If you make your screen double buffered (need to add a flag to `SDL_SetVideoMode()`), you'll render to an off-screen buffer that only becomes visible when you "flip" the buffers (with `SDL_Flip()`)... that way you can make sure the video frames are fully drawn before you see them.  Also, you need to make sure the top-left video is always drawn after drawing the larger video before flipping the buffers so it doesn't get covered up by the larger video that's supposed to be behind it. Currently you're probably seeing the screen while the videos are being drawn to it, causing the "flicking".